# Application crashes on Samsung devices after image taken in PORTRAIT mode

Tags: cordova, android-camera

We have developed an application that takes an image and uploads it to server using FILE URI using PhoneGap. 
The application works perfectly fine with all the devices except for Samsung.
For all devices except Samsung we can take images in Portrait and Landscape mode and can upload them.
With Samsung, we can only take image and upload it in Landscape mode. It gets crashed in Portrait mode. When we take image in Portrait mode, after capturing the image, the image flickers(rotates), if we tap Save button, application goes in hang state and terminates/quits/crashes with the message "unfortunately application stopped".

We have tried to set "correctOrientation" to false. In this case it works excpet the image orientation is completely wrong. we can upload the image in this case.

We have also tried to set targetHeight/targetWidth. In this case also it works, but the image quality get disturbed which is not acceptable. We want to upload the image with original size(dimension).

Can you please help us to fix the problem? Appreciating quick reply.

Thanks in Advance.

Thanks,
Anil.